# Linking timeseries data with point data

Tags: merge, data-analysis

I have some number of manufacturing batch data (say50). Each batch has two types of data: 1) timeseries data (0-280hrs, 1 hour interval, with 3-4 monitoring variables) for each batch and 2) point data (one data point per batch). I want to link the two datasets with BatchID as a common ID.

I used the following code snippet unsuccesfully:

````
merged_data = time_series_data.merge(point_data, on='BatchID')```
``

I get the following error: (I tried checking dtype and all)

'''
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_22808\91818168.py in <module>
----> 1 merged_data = time_series_data.merge(point_data, on='BatchID')
      2 merged_data

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
   9352         from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge
   9353 
-> 9354         return merge(
   9355             self,
   9356             right,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    105     validate: str | None = None,
    106 ) -> DataFrame:
--> 107     op = _MergeOperation(
    108         left,
    109         right,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    698             self.right_join_keys,
    699             self.join_names,
--> 700         ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    701 
    702         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
   1095                     if not is_rkey(rk):
   1096                         if rk is not None:
-> 1097                             right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
   1098                         else:
   1099                             # work-around for merge_asof(right_index=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1838             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1839         else:
-> 1840             raise KeyError(key)
   1841 
   1842         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'BatchID'
'''
````